# Ionic 2: RC.0 Storage no longer works in browser

Tags: sqlite, typescript, storage, ionic2, web-sql

**Q) How can I get my app to work in the browser as before, using WebSQL/SQLite?**

I've been using the ionic `Storage` module since forever, which enabled my app to run with WebSQL in the browser and SQLite on the device itself.

This was simple and working, now it's broken with RC.0.

**My LocalStorageService.ts was like this:**

```
export class LocalStorageService {

  constructor(...) { ... }

  query(sql: string, params?: any, infoMsg?: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      return this._db.executeSql(sql, params).then(
        (data) => {
          this._LogService.info(infoMsg);
          resolve(data);
        },
        (error) => {
          this._LogService.error(error);
          resolve(null);
        }
      );
    });
  }

}
```

**Then I could call it from any component:**

```
this.LocalStorageService.query('SELECT * FROM blah').then(data => {
    // do stuff with results.
});
```

**Note**: Key/value pair storage i.e. LocalStorage won't work, I need SQL querying capabilities in the browser+device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this gist:

https://gist.github.com/NickStemerdink/64c782807fc31b7bc9b529ad4b1d56d5

Original post here:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/8269#issuecomment-250756711